# How does size of training image, training network and inference network affect the accuracy of YOLOv4 Darknet model?

Tags: object-detection, yolo, darknet

Our use case is to train a YOLOv4 network to detect an object as small as a wedding band on top of a table. So the object is about `250px by 250px` in a `4096px x 2160px`.

1. **Training network size:** According to the [README.MD](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/blob/master/README.md#how-to-improve-object-detection), should our training net to be as big as it can fit within the GPU memory? In our case, it's `1056 x 1056` for a Titan T4 with 16GB GPU RAM
2. **Training images size:** For our training images of the object, they are around `1000 px by 1000 px`, from the Darknet documentation I see that it will resize when `random=1`, so I assume we are good with the relatively high resolution training images?
3. **Detection network size:** During the detection, in the same [README.MD](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/blob/master/README.md#how-to-improve-object-detection), the first point of item 2 suggested increasing the network-resolution for detection. So if we were to use 1056x1056 during training, should we use `1280 x 1280` (32 * 40) or larger [net.width and net.height](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/blob/master/cfg/yolov4-custom.cfg#L8-L9)?

Thanks!